# Design consideration for Importing large Excel file data to database in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, excel, import

This being a design approach question, please bear with me for long description :-) 
 
We have a SharePoint web part from where a user can be added to the system. But I am going to work on **bulk user import functionality** in SharePoint.

My question is what all design considerations should be kept in mind while developing this solution. Following is the basic flow i have identified

1. User downloads the import template
   (excel file)
2. Fill in the downloaded import template with user details
3. User uploads the excel sheet
4. System will validate template and data
5. Import data to database from the excel file, row by row
6. For any exception/error log put entire excel record in another excel log file along with the exception details

Here are some of the considerations i had in mind for this flow
For template validation

Export Template

- Generate template based on database columns
- Add column restriction E.g. Data type, Selection of only predefined values

Template Validation

- Check number of columns supported
- Column header names validity

Data Validation

- Check mandatory data presense
- Data type validation
- Data validation against database

Import Process

- This being a SharePoint solution and we might have multiple WFEs, i am thinking of uploading the file to a document library for temporary storage
- Actual import process will be done through some timer job which will pick up from this document library ?
- The log file will be an identical blank template with only header columns and actual records which failed along with error message as an additional column. This should get stored in a separate document library.
- At the end of the process show user a link to download this log file.
- Should i also maintain a record of which all record were successful. Possible number of users to be imported may be in hundreds if not thousands.

Please suggest if i am missing any design considerations here or anything which can be wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Why Excel? Why not CSV? To what are you adding users? Why not use SharePoint lists?

Comment: I need to have field validation in the template, In excel i guess we can achieve that. Can you explain for what purpose you are suggesting to use SharePoint lists ?

Comment: Well you have the Access Data Grid view for bulk data entry. Data can be validated by field type. You can also keep versions of entries, have server-side object model code to act on your items as they are added (or a timer job to do them in bulk) and you can have a column be written to upon success/failure.

Comment: @James, the data I am going to import will belong to different sections which are right now part of different database tables. Add/Edit single user web part is already in place. So i don't think i can use SharePoint list instead and leverage access data grid view functionality.